# div border size is 2px while in inspect its showing 1.6

Tags: html, css

Hello I wrote this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Padding</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #main {
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      border: 2px black solid;
      margin: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    Hello World
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And defined 2px border but when I inspect border size shown is 1.6.
[Inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZEPz.png)

Tried to add CSS code for box but dimension is different while inspecting

Comment: Are you using zoom? With 100% of the zoom you get 2px of border

Comment: Which browser are you using? Are there other relevant CSS rules that apply? I get 2px properly in Firefox and Chrome with your code

Comment: I tried in both Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the resolution of your screen?

In small screens many times the default is of `125%` which could cause that kind of error.

- `125%` it also showed a border of `1.6`
- `100%` showed a border of `2`

(On Chrome it worked well with both resolutions, on Firefox it worked well only with `100%`)

Comment: Thank you so much its working screen resolution was the main problem. Now I have to learn to work in 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing display scale in setting of your computer from 125%(which is recommended value in window) to 100% same with your browser's zoom scale set it to 100%.

This happens because browser applies a scaling factor to the border-width value to display border-width of exactly you mentioned.